# Firebase - app not writing into real time database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build a user registration activity and I want to add a user object to the real-time database. For some reason, I am not able to get anything added to the real-time database, only to the authentication part of Firebase. I don't get any errors or anything, the addValueEventListener just doesn't show any toasts. The progress bar that I make visible at the start just keeps on going and it seems that `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` are never reached. I've seen that usually when this happens the issue is with the database rules, but I think my rules should be fine...

Here are the rules to the real-time database:

```
   {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

And here's the code:

```
registerProgressBar.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterUser.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        User user = new User(username, email);
                        Log.d("User creation", "User has been created");
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("users").setValue(user);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                Log.d("User creation", "Registration successful");
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                registerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                Log.d("User creation", "Registration cancelled");
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Registration cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                registerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        registerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I've honestly tried so many different things and I'm really at a loss on what's wrong. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: The Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. While they both are part of Firebase, they have completely separate API, and the security rules for one have nothing to do with the other. If you are using the Realtime Database, the rules for Firestore are irrelevant. Please remove any information and tags for the database that are not relevant to your question.

Comment: When step through your code line by line in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my post accordingly. In terms of the debugger, it's difficult for me to tell as this is my first project I'm doing with Android Studio, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm meant to be getting after every line. But from my understanding, it seems that the addValueEventListener is the problem. I'm able to create the user object with no problem, but after that is where the program gets stuck. Nothing within onDataChange or onCancelled ever happens. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If neither the `Log.d("User creation", "Registration successful")` nor the `Log.d("User creation", "Registration cancelled");` gets called, that often means the device doesn't have an internet connection, or it can't reach Firebase. I recommend checking the internet connection, and the logcat output for hints as to why that may be.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that's right, neither of them gets called. Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not sure if it can be because of the Internet connection, because the information that I put in gets added to the 'Authentication' section on Firebase but not the real-time database (wouldn't that indicate that the Internet is working fine?). It does seem possible that it just can't reach the Firebase real-time database for some reason, but I really don't understand why, I feel like I set it all up correctly, so I'm just at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: Ah, I had overlooked your `setValue`. You might want to check the logcat output for errors when that line runs, or attach a completion listener as shown here: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `reference.push().setValue(Anything you want to write)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I gave this a try, but it's still not adding anything to the real-time database